# FirebaseUI authState subscribe: returning values

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2, firebaseui

I am having some trouble understanding how to return and use the data returned with angular and FirebasUI (https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebaseui-angular).

For now, I am returning data from the authstate with

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(d => console.log(d));
}
```

and this returns in the console

```
{currentUser: Hk, credential: null, redirectUrl: undefined}
```

my question: how do I access `currentUser` in order to use `*ngIf` to apply conditional formatting of my pages.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I found a way to perform the requested action:

first declare a property in the component class:

```
email: string = 'placeHolder';
```

Then in the subscribe response I assign the needed data from `d`:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(d =>
  {
    console.log(d);
    this.email = d.email;
    if (this.email != 'placeHolder') {
      this.hasEmail = true;
    } else {
      this.hasEmail = false;
    }
  });
```

}

After then I simply use `*ngIf="hasEmail"` in my selectors and it works!

Maybe there is a better solution, but at least this works for me.